# Laravel 5.3 - Image validation not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a problem with the validation of images or mimes overall.

This is my code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:50',
        'content' => 'required|min:20',
        'description' => 'required|max:140',
        'file' => 'image'
    ]);
```

When I try to upload any file I get the error:

> The file failed to upload.

When I dont have the `image` flag, everthing just works fine.

I can put things like `required` or `max:5000`.

I looked at the documentation and it should work, but it doesn't.

So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Added form:

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'PostController@store', 'files' => 'true' ]) !!}

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}<br>
                {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                <small>Max 50 characters</small>

                <br>

                {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}<br>
                {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 2, 'cols' => 50]) !!}
                <small>Max 140 characters</small>

                <br>

                {!! Form::label('content', 'Content:') !!}<br>
                {!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>'content', 'rows' => 8, 'cols' => 50]) !!}

                <br>

                {!! Form::label('file', 'Upload a thumbnail here:') !!} <br>
                {!! Form::file('file', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!} <br>
                <small>Only jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg</small>

            </div>

                {!! Form::submit(null, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

EDIT 2:

added html:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://blog.luukwuijster.eu" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="N72xyc8mmbdFGrS78sdhIqh25awN30AboL9ecqGm">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="title">Title:</label><br>
                <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" id="title">
                <small>Max 50 characters</small>

                <br>

                <label for="description">Description:</label><br>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" cols="50" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
                <small>Max 140 characters</small>

                <br>

                <label for="content">Content:</label><br>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="8" cols="50" name="content" style="display: none;"></textarea>

                <br>

                <label for="file">Upload a thumbnail here:</label> <br>
                <input name="file" type="file" id="file"> <br>
                <small>Only jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg</small>

            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">

            </form>
```

EDIT 3:

added the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use GrahamCampbell\Markdown\Facades\Markdown;

class PostController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('index', 'show');
}

public function index()
{

    $posts = Post::latest()->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('posts'));
}


/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $file = $request->file('file');

    if($file){
        $name = rand(1, 1000000000).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('images', $name);

        $input['thumbnail'] = $name;
    }else{
        $input['thumbnail'] = "No_Image.png";
    }

    //TODO: validatie voor de thumbnails.

    $this->validate($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|max:50',
        'content' => 'required|min:20',
        'description' => 'required|max:140',
        'file' => 'image'
    ]);

    Auth::user()->post()->create($input);

    return redirect('/');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $content = Markdown::convertToHtml($post->content);

    return view('post', compact('post', 'content'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Auth::user()->post()->findOrFail($id);
    return view('edit', compact('post'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $file = $request->file('file');

    if($file){
        $name = rand(1, 1000000000).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('images', $name);

        $input['thumbnail'] = $name;
    }

    //TODO: validatie voor de thumbnails.

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:50',
        'content' => 'required|min:20',
        'description' => 'required|max:140',
        'file' => 'image'
    ]);

    Auth::user()->post()->findOrFail($id)->update($input);

    return redirect('/home');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    Auth::user()->post()->withTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->forceDelete();

    return redirect('/recyclebin');
}

public function restore($id)
{
    Auth::user()->post()->withTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->restore();

    return redirect('/home');
}

public function recyclebin()
{
    $posts = Post::onlyTrashed()->get();

    return view('recyclebin', compact('posts'));
}

public function remove($id){

    //Post::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    Auth::user()->post()->findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return redirect('/home');

}
}
```

Comment: can you show me your form?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: I don't know if this can be a problem, but maybe it's because of `'files' => 'true'` (you put true in ' '). Try changing to `'files' => true`, @Luuk Wuijster . Show me your form you get in web source

Comment: No, that does not work, and I added the html to the post

Comment: Is this a FormRequest validation or inside a controller? Posting the whole controller or custom form request would be helpful for Troubleshooting. If this is in a controller, you should change $request to $request->all() inside the validate method

Comment: Its inside the controller, because I was getting a forbidden error when I did with a custom request. And I changed the `$request` to `$request->all()` but that throws a Type error:
validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

Comment: Added the controller to the post.

Comment: Sorry, you were correct in not using all(). I usually use the Validator::make method in my controllers, which requires all(). I would give that a shot just to rule out any issue with $this->validate https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: Actually, just looking over your controller, it looks like you are moving the file before trying to validate. Try moving your validation block ahead of your if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you controller like this --

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:50',
        'content' => 'required|min:20',
        'description' => 'required|max:140',
        'file' => 'image'
    ]);
    $input = $request->all();

    $file = $request->file('file');

    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $name = rand(1, 1000000000).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('images', $name);

        $input['thumbnail'] = $name;
    }else{
        $input['thumbnail'] = "No_Image.png";
    }

    Auth::user()->post()->create($input);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

And changing `'files' => 'true'` to `'files' => true`

Answer (score 11):

In your opening form tag add this:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

and in the file input(where you actually upload it), add this:

```
multiple="multiple"
```

**Edit:**
In every form you should use the `csrf_field()` method. add also just befor the openning form tag.

2019 update:
You can add the `@csrf` directive instead of `csrf_field()` method. It's the same, just more convenient for some people.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: if I remember, `'files' => true` should do the job (write that `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ). Am I not right?

Comment: No, not working.
And Form::open() automatically adds a csrf_field().

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [  
   'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
])
if ($validator - > fails()) {
   return $this - > sendError('Validation Error.', $validator - > errors());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.